# Magento 2.3.2 version upgrade to 2.4.0

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento-upgrade, magento2.4, php-7.3

I am afraid of  upgrading my magento version because my store is all setup. My php version is `7.3.20` and I thinking of upgrading to

```
magento version 2.4.0


composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

Will it cause conflicts?

Comment: composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update should work no issues and should not cause any conflicts. the only conflicts you may see is with 3rd party modules. once you have upgraded your magento version run composer update which should update all 3rd party modules in the vendor directory if you have modules in app/code you will need to upgrade these manually

Comment: @Anonymous Record, first takes backup and try it.

Answer (score 0):

First take the backup of your magento and database

In composer.json file update **"magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2"**  to  **"magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.0"**

Now run the below command:-

1. bin/php -d memory_limit=-1  vendor/composer/composer/bin/composer update
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
4. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
6. php bin/magento cache:clean

check your Magento version with the Below command
php bin/magento --version

It will update your magento version and all the modules.